# How to Calculate Sum of nth <tr> Height to the Selected Row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to scroll to position of a `<tr>` in a table wrapped in a div with vertical Scroolbar. What I want to do is calculating the sum of all  until selected `<tr>` number which I am able to get the number by using this code

```
var trh = $('tr.' + this.id).index()+1;
```

but I am not able to calculate the sum of each rows until selected index. I cant set a defined row height since the table's row have different height according to data which they contain. here is my try:

```
var trh = $('tr.' + this.id).index()+1;
$('table:tr('+trh+')').each(function() {
   sum += $(this).height();
 });
$('#myscroller').scrollTop(sum);
```

Can you please let me know how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just get the offset / position of the target and then scroll to this position.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/